# Close a test using Selenium Webdriver PHP

Tags: php, selenium, testing, webdriver

Here's how I write my tests:

A class with private methods and a single public method which runs all my others private methods.

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private function firstScenario() {
        $this->navigation = new Navigation($this->webDriver);
        $this->navigation->goToPointA();
        //...
    }

    private function secondScenario() {
        $this->navigation = new Navigation($this->webDriver);
        $this->navigation->goToPointA();
        //...
    }

    public function testRun() {
        //...
        $this->firstScenario();
        $this->secondScenario();
        //...
    }
```

I have in other classes some generic methods, whose one named Navigation.php. In this class, I have all my methods which enable me to go to a specific point of my application.

All I want to do is, according to a condition, to close (or quit, or dispose, or whatever you want) my test, properly, without returning an error. I tried quit(), close() and dispose() but maybe I use its wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably add quit() to your tear down. Depending on how you are invoking `driver` it would be something like:

```
protected function tearDown() {
   if ($this->driver) {
      $this->driver->quit();
   }
}
```